# Defining x ticks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
     bnw_Percent  bnw_Value  mtgp_Percent  mtgp_Value  php_Percent  php_Value  
0      0.004414    1.48150      0.010767     2.03548     0.028395    3.91826   
1      0.015450    5.44825      0.020337     6.01205     0.352093    7.77627   
2      0.059593    9.41501      0.043067     9.98863     1.118746   11.63430   
3      0.156709   13.38180      0.137575    13.96520     1.164177   15.49230   
4      0.355353   17.34850      0.242849    17.94180     1.436765   19.35030   
5      0.560620   21.31530      0.436650    21.91840     1.635527   23.20830   
6      0.896109   25.28200      0.695051    25.89490     1.839968   27.06630   
7      1.436864   29.24880      1.208264    29.87150     2.169345   30.92430   
8      2.145364   33.21550      2.025338    33.84810     3.219944   34.78230   
9      3.412276   37.18230      3.423814    37.82470     4.514737   38.64030   
10     5.566469   41.14910      5.351055    41.80120     6.542109   42.49830   
11     9.188426   45.11580      8.220981    45.77780     9.233914   46.35640   
12    14.300219   49.08260     12.081444    49.75440    12.010904   50.21440   
13    18.072263   53.04930     16.622603    53.73100    13.833835   54.07240   
14    19.641556   57.01610     20.070343    57.70750    13.788404   57.93040   
15    14.682058   60.98280     16.976708    61.68410    12.715089   61.78840   
16     7.237292   64.94960      9.493845    65.66070     9.489466   65.64640   
17     2.057077   68.91640      2.672537    69.63730     4.100176   69.50440   
18     0.211888   72.88310      0.265579    73.61380     0.800727   73.36240   
19     0.000000   76.84990      0.001196    77.59040     0.005679   77.22040
```

and I am making a plot with the following code:

```
plot=df.plot(x=['bnw_Value', 'mtgp_Value', 'php_Value'], y=['bnw_Percent', 'php_Percent', 'mtgp_Percent'],  title='Frequency Distribution of Fuzzy Accumulated Values')
plot.set_xlabel('Value')
plot.set_ylabel('Percent')
plot.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

which looks like this:

[image]

my problem is this results in overlapping x-axis values, what I really want is something like the minimum value found in any of `bnw_Value`, `mtgp_Value` or `php_Value` and the maximum value in any of the those three columns in increments of 10. Or at least for the x axis to be readable somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
df.plot(x=df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Value' in col]].min(axis=1),
        y=['bnw_Percent', 'php_Percent', 'mtgp_Percent'],
        title='Frequency Distribution of Fuzzy Accumulated Values')
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
In [24]: [col for col in df.columns if 'Value' in col]
Out[24]: ['bnw_Value', 'mtgp_Value', 'php_Value']

In [25]: df[[col for col in df.columns if 'Value' in col]].min(axis=1)
Out[25]:
0      1.48150
1      5.44825
2      9.41501
3     13.38180
4     17.34850
5     21.31530
6     25.28200
7     29.24880
8     33.21550
9     37.18230
10    41.14910
11    45.11580
12    49.08260
13    53.04930
14    57.01610
15    60.98280
16    64.94960
17    68.91640
18    72.88310
19    76.84990
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rotation (e.g. 20):

```
plot=df.plot(x=['bnw_Value', 'mtgp_Value', 'php_Value'], 
             y=['bnw_Percent', 'php_Percent', 'mtgp_Percent'],  
             rot=20,
             title='Frequency Distribution of Fuzzy Accumulated Values')
```